# Как сделать добавление значении в массив map?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть данные которые я получил от mysql. Это тесты, я получил все вопросы и нужно их в массив загнать все полученные по выборке значение. И хочу все ответы переместить в массив.
Чтобы все это показать

```js
const Router = require('koa-router'),
    Test = require('./model/test'),
    router = new Router();
router.get('/testing/:id', async ctx => {
        let theme = await Test.theme(ctx.params.id);
        let test = await Test.test(ctx.params.id);
        let answearArr = test.map(item => {
            Test.answear(item.id);
        });
        console.log(answearArr);
    })
```

Получаю массив вот такой
[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
Внутри item находится следующий массив

```
RowDataPacket {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Первый вопрос',
  id_theme: 1 }
RowDataPacket {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Второй вопрос?',
  id_theme: 1 }
RowDataPacket {
  id: 4,
  name: 'Третий вопрос',
  id_theme: 1 }
```

Чтобы понимаю что находится в переменной

```js
const db = require('../bin/db');

let Test = {
    test: function(id){
        return requestTest('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id_theme = ?', id);
    },
    answear: function(id){
        return requestTest('SELECT * FROM answers WHERE id_question = ?', id);
    },
    theme: function(id){
        return requestTest('SELECT name FROM thema WHERE id = ?', id);
    }
};

function requestTest(sql, req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(
            sql,
            [req],
            (err, rows) => {
                if(err) reject(err);
                resolve(rows);
            });
    }).then(rows => {return rows;});
}

module.exports = Test;
```

Comment: это наверное какой нить node.js ? у вас методы асинхронные, в массив складываются данные раньше, чем ответ приходит. другие то у вас с `await` вызываются, а ответы без. в любом случае, тянуть отдельным запросом ответы на каждый вопрос не есть хорошо.

Comment: вы верните пачкой все ответы для всего теста, а потом распихайте что-куда.

Comment: Она также пачкой возвращается все вопросы, по определенному id . В ответе там просто в самом ответе хранятся правильный ответ или нет. То есть обычное обозначение 1 или 0. Узнал что не работает item.id это массив приходит значени и соответственно данный запрос ожидает одно значение а получает массив

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
router.get('/testing/:id', async ctx => {
        let theme = await Test.theme(ctx.params.id);
        let test = await Test.test(ctx.params.id);
        let answearArr = await Promise.all(test.map(item => {
            return Test.answear(item.id);
        })).then(id => id);
        console.log(answearArr);
        await ctx.render('test', {
            title: 'Тест',
            path: 'test',
        })
    })
```

```js
answear: function(id){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.query(
                `SELECT * FROM answers WHERE id_question IN (?)`,
                id,
                (err, rows) => {
                    if(err) reject(err);
                    resolve(rows);
                });
        }).then(rows => {return rows;});
    },
```